# In reactjs how to cancel onbeforeunload event? ,,,, Please Can someone Give example,,, on jsfiddle,sandbox ,,etc,,

Tags: javascript, reactjs

can some one suggest me an example that if user have enter data in input ,,, then if user want to close tab/browser show alert for unsaved work,,,,,

**But ,,, then if user blank the input form then,,if user close tab/browser,,, it should not show alert for unsaved work**

**I tried  remove event listener,,, *with condition* but failed**

I have added addevent listener using this,,,,

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload',(event)=> {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.returnValue = ' message for unsaved work;
 }, true );



window.removeEventListener('beforeunload',(event)=> {
                event.preventDefault();
                event.returnValue = ' message for unsaved work;
     }, true );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using functional components and hooks you can do it like shown here: https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-brattain-uufyg?file=/src/App.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const handler = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (text === "") {
        return;
      }
      e.returnValue = true;
    };

    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", handler);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", handler);
  }, [text]);

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={text}
        onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

The useEffect will be called every time "text" changes and always register a new beforeunload handler that then can use the information in the state to decide if the unload should be stopped or not.

Comment: thank you,,,  i really wanted answer for functional component,,

Answer (score 1):

You could use `componentDidMount()` and `componentWillUnmount()` to set/remove "beforeunload" event listener it will show only if you have data entered

### **Demo**

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  
  state={firstName:""}
  handletabClose = (ev) => {
  ev.preventDefault();
  if (this.state.firstName == "") return;
  ev.returnValue = true;
    };
 
 handlechange=(e)=> {
    const { name, value} = e.target;
   this.setState({ [name]: value });
  }
componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", this.handletabClose);
  }
componentWillUnmount(){
    window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", this.handletabClose);
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <label>
            FirstName
            <input
              type="text"
              name="firstName"
              value={this.state.firstName}
              onChange={this.handlechange}
            />
          </label>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: thank you.... very much....,, your answer helped me for class component,,,,